# Delete file when file download is complete on Python x Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I can download the file with the following code(Python x Django).

```
file = open(file_path, 'w')
file.write(text)
file.close()

if os.path.exists(file_path):                                                                
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as fsock:
        filename = urllib.parse.quote(filename)                                                     
        response = HttpResponse()                                                            
        response['content_type'] = 'text/plain'                                              
        response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename='{}'; filename*=UTF-8''{}".format(filename,filename)
        response.write(fsock.read())                                                         
        return response
```

The file to download is generated before downloading.
At this time, is it possible to implement deletion of files when downloading is complete?

Comment: Os.remove after f.write . Also return response outside with statement

Comment: @itzMEonTV wow very easy...It worked after adding `os.remove(file_path)` before `return response`. Does this mean that python is loading the file contents into the response object? So, does that mean that python consumes as much memory as the file size?